# Play a melody on click

Tags: android

When I click on a view, I want to play a melody. The problem is that when I click very fast, the melody starts from the beginning and I want it to play to the end and at this time screen must not react to clicks (because I don't want the melody to be played 10 times if I clicked very fast 10 times). I wrote something like this:

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.cow_moo);
                                      mp.start();
                if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                    img1.setClickable(false);
                    }
                img1.setClickable(true);`

But after one click the screen does not react to click anymore... Help me please with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Init your MediaPlayer when Activity is created, for instance:
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.cow_moo);
//**************************//

//onClickListener goes here:

if(mp.isPlaying()){
   //do nothing
}else{
   mp.start(); 
}

//onClickListener ends here:
```

Comment: unbelievable! such a simple solution and it works just great! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Read the [android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html), it says "If you wish to later replay the media, then you must reset() and prepare() the MediaPlayer object before calling start() again"

Comment: I really don't have time for reading all this material and I'm not sure how it can help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: I already mentioned the most important part of the article: to play something again, you have to call reset() and prepare() before calling start() again. Unless you want to create a new MediaPlayer each time the user clicks on the button which would be a waste of resources.

Comment: ok, first I will refactor all my code and try to do this. I'll write about what I did later ;)

Comment: I wrote like you said `public void onClickPlay() {
  if (player.isPlaying()) {
   // do nothing
  } else {
   try { player.reset();
     player.prepare();
     player.start();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   };
  }` As I initialize player in onCreate() method, and then reset it on click, I have no resource to play.

Answer (score 0):

Upon click event check if the media player has finished its playback. If no, then do nothing, if yes then play again.

To check if finished use this method below:
isPlaying()

You may check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Hope you find it easy. :)